# Use netbeans to create oracle Jet application: Project folder is already NetBeans project (maybe only in memory)

Tags: java, oracle, netbeans, oracle-jet

I can not create a O-Jet application because of "Project folder is already NetBeans project (maybe only in memory)." issue.
I have googled this issue and deleted nbproject folder and re-start netbeans, but when I create the application again it throws the same error.
The IDE version:Netbeans 8.1

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to "create" a JET project with NetBeans.  Just open it.  NetBeans will automatically recognize the folder as a project because of the package.json file that is included (that indicates to NetBeans that it is a Node based project).

Comment: Thanks...but the thing is that now I don't have a Jet application, I just need to create one from Netbeans using "Oracle JET Base Distribution".

Answer (score 0):

Finally I changed the **name** of the application because I usually use the default name. Although I have deleted the application with the same name, there maybe something remaining in memory which results in this issue.